# how to get porcupine-web-react-demo working?

Tags: reactjs, voice-recognition, voice

Getting an error when trying the local demo version of the app. Getting a similar error when trying to use my own phrase model.

Error: "'pv_porcupine_init' failed with status INVALID_ARGUMENT\nDetails: "

The error above happens when I try to init porcupine.

Demo: https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/demo/react
Platform: Mac M1, Ventura 13.3, latest Chrome browser.

I ensured I am using the latest lis based on read me and provided access key.

[image]

Comment: Turns out you need to pass a forceWrite boolean like so:     await init(
      ACCESS_KEY,
      {
        "base64": heyFriendModel,
        "label": FRIEND_KEYWORD_LABEL,
        forceWrite: true
      },
      {base64: modelParams, forceWrite: true}
    );